# How to add generic condition to sp select?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I really don't know what to do in this situation, so don't be too harsh.

If I have my select:

```
declare @Id uniqueidentifier = 'some parent guid'
declare @Type int = 1 -- can be 1, 2 or 3
declare @UserType varchar(max) --can be 0, anything else than 0, or all users at once

if(@Type = 1)
set @UserType = 'and UserType <> 0'
if(@Type = 2)
set @UserType = 'and UserType = 0'
if(@Type = 3)
set @UserType = ''
    select * from users where parentId = @Id + @UserType
```

What to do in the situation where condition is "generic"? Do i really need to create 3 different Sp?

Comment: Different select statements would be most efficient since each is a fundamentally different query.  Below is a dynamic SQL example using techniques from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `AND/OR` logic to simulate the `If-else` condition in `where` clause. Try something like this

```
select * from users 
where
parentid= @id 
and 
(
(@Type = 1 and UserType <> 0)
or 
(@Type = 2 and UserType = 0)
or 
(@Type = 3)
)
```

or you can also use `Dynamic sql` to do this

```
declare @Id uniqueidentifier = 'some parent guid'
declare @Type int = 1 -- can be 1, 2 or 3
Declare @UserType varchar(max) --can be 0, anything else than 0, or all users at once
Declare @sql nvarchar(max)

if(@Type = 1)
set @UserType = ' and UserType <> 0'
if(@Type = 2)
set @UserType = ' and UserType = 0'
if(@Type = 3)
set @UserType = ''

set @sql = 'select * from users where parentId ='''+ cast(@Id as varchar(25))+''''+ @UserType 

--Print @sql

Exec sp_executesql @sql
```

Answer (score 0):

Different select statements would be most efficient since each is a fundamentally different query.  If static SQL becomes unwieldly, use dynamic SQL.  Below is a parameterized example using techniques from http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html.

```
declare @sql nvarchar(MAX) = N'select * from users where parentId = @Id';
declare @Id uniqueidentifier = 'some parent guid';
declare @Type int = 1; -- can be 1, 2 or 3
declare @UserType varchar(max); --can be 0, anything else than 0, or all users at once

SET @sql = @sql + CASE @Type
    WHEN 1 THEN N' and UserType <> 0'
    WHEN 2 THEN N' and UserType = 0'
    WHEN 3 THEN N'' END;

EXEC sp_executesql
      @sql
    , N'@Id uniqueidentifier'
    , @Id = @Id;
```